# What is the difference between AP Calculus and Calculus ? Calculus is a mat. analysis?

Tags: calculus, education

I study myself and study math in English. Khan Academy is my main resource in the development of mathematics, but there courses are made on the American system. I do not know how the AP Calculus of the differ from the usual Calculus 1 and 2. Is calculus a mathematical analysis?

Comment: AP stands for “Advanced Placement” and is typically taken by excelling high school students (in my case, all of the AP courses I took corresponded to the first one or two semesters in college for those courses; that is, AP Calculus was roughly the same material and the same difficulty as my first-semester calculus course). I’m not familiar with Khan Academy, but it may be similar.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Is calculus a mathematical analysis," but if you go through Khan Academy it will cover everything in AP Calculus AB and BC. My only recommendation is do more problems than what Khan Academy gives you.

Comment: sometimes calculus is referred as analysis. I would say that "calculus" is a sub-field of analysis (which also contains functional analysis, pde, complex analysis, etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, "AP" stands for Advanced Placement, which is an advanced, international version of the usual national end-of-high-school exams (you may be familiar with the "A-levels" system in the UK, for example).  AP Calculus is separated into Calculus AB and Calculus BC, which very roughly speaking are the usual Calculus I (limits, basic differentiation, integration) and Calculus II (integration techniques, more applications). These are usually at the level of a first-semester calculus course in an average university.

Analysis on the other hand is a word that's often used for the more advanced topics which grow from the same vein as calculus. Real Analysis, very roughly speaking, deals with putting the ideas in calculus on rigorous mathematical footing, and often also will discuss basic ideas in topology and whatnot. Complex analysis does the same thing for complex functions, and functional analysis does it for functionals, and so on. I would recommend against worrying about analysis for now, if you're just beginning to study calculus.

Comment: I have not yet begun to study this topic, I am very far away, but I want to create a clear plan for achieving the goal. And thanks to you, I already more or less know how to build it. But here is the question after which topic in mathematics should I go into mathematical analysis? Or rather, from which topic can I plunge into the mathematical analysis?

Comment: A typical learning curve might be AP Calculus, Multivariable Calculus, Ordinary Differential Equations, then Linear Algebra, Real Analysis and Abstract Algebra in more or less that order (though of course you can mix up the order of anything after Calculus as you see fit). From then on, you can go on to do whatever you like; PDEs, Complex Analysis, Combinatorics, Number Theory and Topology are the most famous ones.